# Schönauer Triad Benchmark - L1D Cache not visible

Tags: c, caching, gcc, benchmarking, hpc

We are two HPC students getting involved into the famous Schönauer Triad Benchmark, whose C code are reported here along with its short explanation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/time.h>

#define DEFAULT_NMAX 10000000
#define DEFAULT_NR DEFAULT_NMAX
#define DEFAULT_INC 10
#define DEFAULT_XIDX 0

#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 1024

// #define WINOS
#define STACKALLOC

#ifdef WINOS 
    #include <windows.h>
#endif

static void dummy(double A[], double B[], double C[], double D[])
{
    return;
}

static double simulation(int N, int R)
{
    int i, j;

    #ifdef STACKALLOC
        double A[N];
        double B[N];
        double C[N];
        double D[N];
    #else
        double * A = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
        double * B = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
        double * C = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
        double * D = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    #endif

    double elaps;

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        A[i] = 0.00;
        B[i] = 1.00;
        C[i] = 2.00;
        D[i] = 3.00;
    }

    #ifdef WINOS
        FILETIME tp;
        GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&tp);
        elaps = - (double)(((ULONGLONG)tp.dwHighDateTime << 32) | (ULONGLONG)tp.dwLowDateTime)/10000000.0;
    #else
        struct timeval tp;
        gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
        elaps = -(double)(tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_usec/1000000.0);
    #endif

    for(j=0; j<R; ++j)
    {
        for(i=0; i<N; ++i)
            A[i] = B[i] + C[i]*D[i];

        if(A[2] < 0) dummy(A, B, C, D);
    }

    #ifndef STACKALLOC
        free(A);
        free(B); 
        free(C);
        free(D);
    #endif

    #ifdef WINOS
        GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(&tp);
        return elaps + (double)(((ULONGLONG)tp.dwHighDateTime << 32) | (ULONGLONG)tp.dwLowDateTime)/10000000.0;
    #else
        gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
        return elaps + ((double)(tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_usec/1000000.0));
    #endif
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int NR = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : DEFAULT_NR;
    const int NMAX = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) : DEFAULT_NMAX;
    const int inc = argc > 3 ? atoi(argv[3]) : DEFAULT_INC;
    const int xidx = argc > 4 ? atoi(argv[4]) : DEFAULT_XIDX;

    int i, j, k;
    FILE * fp;

    printf("\n*** Schonauer Triad benchmark ***\n");

    char csvname[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
    sprintf(csvname, "data%d.csv", xidx);

    if(!(fp = fopen(csvname, "a+")))
    {
        printf("\nError whilst writing to file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int R, N;
    double MFLOPS;
    double elaps;

    for(N=1; N<=NMAX; N += inc)
    {
        R = NR/N;
        elaps = simulation(N, R);
        MFLOPS = ((R*N)<<1)/(elaps*1000000);
        fprintf(fp, "%d,%lf\n", N, MFLOPS);
        printf("N = %d, R = %d\n", N, R);
        printf("Elapsed time: %lf\n", elaps);
        printf("MFLOPS: %lf\n", MFLOPS);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    (void) getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The code simply loops over N and for each *N*, it does *NR* floating point operations, where *NR* is a constant that stands for the number of constant operations to do at each outermost iteration, in order to take accurate time measurements even for too short N values. The kernel to analyze is obviously the *simulation* subroutine.

We've got some strange results:

We started with benchmarking the kernel on an *E4 E9220 server 2U*, consisting of 8 nodes, each of them equipped with dual-socket *Intel Xeon E5-2697 V2 (Ivy Bridge) @ 2,7 GHz, 12 cores*. The code has been compiled with *gcc (GCC) 4.8.2*, and has been run on *Linux CentOS release 6*. Below are listed the resulting plots in a single image:

[N versus MFlops plots: -Ofast (above) and -Ofast along -march=native (below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ovxm.png)

It is straightforward to see that L2 and L3 downhills are pretty visible, and they are numerically OK by doing some simple calculations and taking into account multiprogramming issues and the facts that L2-L3 are UNIFIED and L3 are also SHARED among all 12 cores. In the first plot L1 is not visible, while in the second it is visible and it starts in an N value so the resulting L1D saturation value is exactly 32 KB, according to the per-core L1D size. The first question is: **why don't we see L1 downhill without *-march=native* architecture specialization flag?**

After some tricky (obviously wrong) self-explanations, we decided to do the benchmark on a *Lenovo Z500*, equipped with a single socket *Intel Core i7-3632QM (Ivy Bridge) @ 2.2 GHz*. This time we've used gcc *(Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406* (from *gcc --version*), and the resulting plots are listed below:

[N versus MFlops plots: -Ofast (above) and -Ofast along -march=native (below)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqcwI.png)

The second question is somewhat spontaneous: **why we see L1D downhill without *-march=native-* this time?**

Comment: There are hardware prefetchers around the different layers of caches in Intel and AMD. They will detect linear accesses and prefetch data for next iterations (and can be disabled https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/disclosure-of-hw-prefetcher-control-on-some-intel-processors). Read posts by McCalpin, John (Dr Bandwidth), the author of modern STREAM Triad http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/, http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~mccalpin/. Also check malloc, NUMA settings and THP (hugepage) settings of big machines. And compare the real asm code between `-Ofast` / `-Ofast -march=native`.

Comment: You're definitely right. The weirdest thing is that we tried also other machines of different Intel families and we've compiled with GCC pre-4.8.5 versions. The result is that L1D descent is still missing on compiling only with _-Ofast_ flag set. Apparently by compiling with GCC 6.3.0 produces the expected result.

Comment: Marco, please post exact disassembly of the inner loop both from `-Ofast` and `-Ofast -march=native` with the "GCC pre-4.8.5 versions" (and probably gcc 6.3.0). (with `perf record ./program` then `perf report` and assembly or `perf annotate`). We may talk about assembly and compiler, not about not reproducible pictures. Some programs probably got no right vectorization like AVX/AVX2. What is the N on the picture for L1 point? This Triad is not best variant of STREAM, it has no "warm-up iterations" - there are extra pagefaults for stack allocation; do 1 NMAX simulation run before the test.

Comment: Ok osgx, thank you for the simple how-to-disassembly. I posted on pastebin the output of the perf record and perf annotate, all the eight combinations:

[output of perf report -Ofast with GCC 4.8.5 @ Pastebin](https://pastebin.ca/3821765) 
[output of perf annotate -Ofast with GCC 4.8.5 @ Pastebin](https://pastebin.ca/3821771) 
[output of perf report -Ofast + -march=native with GCC 4.8.5](http://pastebin.ca/3821776)
[output of perf annotate -Ofast + -march=native with GCC 4.8.5](http://pastebin.ca/3821778)

Comment: Sorry for the double post, here

[output of perf report -Ofast with GCC 6.3.0 @ Pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/3821779) 
[output of perf annotate -Ofast with GCC 6.3.0 @ Pastebin](http://pastebin.ca/3821787) 
[output of perf report -Ofast + -march=native with GCC 6.3.0](http://pastebin.ca/3821790)
[output of perf annotate -Ofast + -march=native with GCC 6.3.0](http://pastebin.ca/3821796)

The only thing I can say is that with -Ofast and -march=native, both in two version of executables (GCC 4.8.5 and 6.3.0 - compiled) , there are vector instructions (prefixed with 'v' in the assembly)

Answer (score 0):

There are assembly fragments of inner "TRIAD" loop (`A[i] = B[i] + C[i]*D[i]`: per `i` iteration 2 double_precision flops, 3 reads of double, 1 write of double).

Exact percents from `perf annotate` was not very useful, as you profiled all regions with different performance into single run. And long perf report not useful at all, only 5-10 first lines after `#` are usually needed. You may try to limit the test to the interesting region of 4*N*sizeof(double) < sizeof(L1d_cache) and recollect perf annotate and also get results of `perf stat ./program` and `perf stat -d ./program` (and also learn about Intel-specific perf wrapper `ocperf.py` - https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools and other tools there).

From `gcc-6.3.0 -Ofast` - 128-bit (2 doubles) [XMM registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) and [SSE2 movupd/movups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#SSE2_instructions) are used (SSE2 is default FPU for x86_64 cpu), 2 iterations of `i` for every assembler loop (movupd loads 2 doubles from memory)

```
         :                              A[i] = B[i] + C[i]*D[i];
    0.03 :        d70:       movupd (%r11,%rax,1),%xmm1    # load C[i:i+1] into xmm1
   14.87 :        d76:       add    $0x1,%ecx              # advance 'i/2' loop counter by 1
    0.10 :        d79:       movupd (%r10,%rax,1),%xmm0    # load D[i:i+1] into xmm0
   14.59 :        d7f:       mulpd  %xmm1,%xmm0            # multiply them into xmm0
    2.78 :        d83:       addpd  (%r14,%rax,1),%xmm0    # load B[i:i+1] and add to xmm0
   17.69 :        d89:       movups %xmm0,(%rsi,%rax,1)    # store into A[i:i+1]
    2.71 :        d8d:       add    $0x10,%rax             # advance array pointer by 2 doubles (0x10=16=2*8)
    1.68 :        d91:       cmp    %edi,%ecx              # check for end of loop (edi is N/2)
    0.00 :        d93:       jb     d70 <main+0x4c0>       # if not, jump to 0xd70
```

From `gcc-6.3.0 -Ofast -march=native`: vmovupd are not just vector (SSE2 *something*pd are vector too), they are [AVX instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) which may use 2 times wide registers YMM (256 bits, 4 doubles per register). There is longer loop but 4 `i` iterations are processed per loop iteration

```
    0.02 :        db6:       vmovupd (%r10,%rdx,1),%xmm0   # load C[i:i+1] into xmm0 (low part of ymm0)
    8.42 :        dbc:       vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r10,%rdx,1),%ymm0,%ymm1  # load C[i+2:i+3] into high part of ymm1 and copy xmm0 into lower part; ymm1 is C[i:i+3]
    7.37 :        dc4:       add    $0x1,%esi              # loop counter ++
    0.06 :        dc7:       vmovupd (%r9,%rdx,1),%xmm0    # load D[i:i+1] -> xmm0
   15.05 :        dcd:       vinsertf128 $0x1,0x10(%r9,%rdx,1),%ymm0,%ymm0  # load D[i+2:i+3] and get D[i:i+3] in ymm0
    0.85 :        dd5:       vmulpd %ymm0,%ymm1,%ymm0      # mul C[i:i+3] and D[i:i+3] into ymm0
    1.65 :        dd9:       vaddpd (%r11,%rdx,1),%ymm0,%ymm0  # soad 4 doubles of B[i:i+3] and add to ymm0
   21.18 :        ddf:       vmovups %xmm0,(%r8,%rdx,1)    # store low 2 doubles to A[i:i+1]
    1.24 :        de5:       vextractf128 $0x1,%ymm0,0x10(%r8,%rdx,1)  # store high 2 doubles to A[i+2:i+3]
    2.04 :        ded:       add    $0x20,%rdx             # advance array pointer by 4 doubles
    0.02 :        df1:       cmp    -0x460(%rbp),%esi      # loop cmp
    0.00 :        df7:       jb     db6 <main+0x506>       # loop jump to 0xdb6
```

The code with AVX enabled (with `-march=native`) is better as it uses better unroll, but it uses narrow loads of 2 doubles. With more real tests arrays will be better aligned and compiler may select widest [256-bit vmovupd](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVUPD.html) into ymm, without need of insert/extract instructions.

**The code you have now probably may be so slow** that it is **unable** to fully load (**saturate**) **interface to L1 data cache** in most cases with short arrays. Another possibility is bad alignment between arrays.

You have short spike of high bandwidth in lower graph in https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ovxm.png - 6 "GFLOPS" and it is strange. Do the calculation to convert this into GByte/s and find the L1d bandwidth of Ivy Bridge and limitations of load issue rate... something like https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/532346 "*Haswell core can only issue two loads per cycle, so they have to be 256-bit AVX loads to have any chance of achieving a rate of 64 Bytes/cycle.*" (The word of expert in TRIAD and author of STREAM, John D. McCalpin, PhD "Dr. Bandwidth", do search for his posts) and http://www.overclock.net/t/1541624/how-much-bandwidth-is-in-cpu-cache-and-how-is-it-calculated "*L1 bandwidth depends on the instructions per tick and the stride of the instructions (AVX = 256-bit, SSE = 128-bit etc.). IIRC, Sandy Bridge has 1 instruction per tick*"

Comment: Check Sandy Bridge (Ivy has same parameters) part of image: https://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cachebw.jpg & https://www.bdti.com/sites/default/files/insidedsp/articlepix/201205/SandyBridgeMicroarchitecture.png - L1 Load is up to 32 Bytes/cycle; L1 store BW is up to 16 Bytes/cycle. Also recompute test results from GB/s to Bytes/tick (get real frequency from output of `perf stat ./program`). 32B/s ld are 1 vmovupd ymm (4 doubles) per tick, 3 cycle needed to read B,C,D with 4-wide unroll/vectorize; 16B/c st is 1 vmovups xmm, so 2 cycle for A[i:i+3] store. Mul/add may overlap